# PHP binding method to another class

Tags: php, php-7

Can i bind method of class Foo to class Bar? And why the code below throws a warning "Cannot bind method Foo::say() to object of class Bar"? With function instead of method code works fine.

P.S. I know about extending)  it is not practical question, just want to know is it real to bind non-static method to another class

```
class Foo {

    public $text = 'Hello World!';

    public function say() {
        echo $this->text;
    }

}

class Bar {

    public $text = 'Bye World!';

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $test = Closure::fromCallable(array(new Foo, 'say'));
        $res = Closure::bind($test, $this);
        return $res();
    }

}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->say();
```

Code below works fine

```
 function say(){
    echo $this->text;
 }
 class Bar {

    public $text = 'Bye World!';

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $test = Closure::fromCallable('say');
        $res = Closure::bind($test, $this);
        return $res();
    }

}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->say();
```

Comment: you can extend to that class

Comment: not sure, but maybe try changing `say()` to be static?

Comment: I know it)  but this question about closures and binding

Comment: I revisited your question and I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by: *"just want to know is it real to bind non-static method to another class"* ?

Comment: For me it is obvious.. in JS it is often used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not supported. If you want to bind a closure to a new object, it must not be a fake closure, or the new object must be compatible with the old one ([source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_closures.c#L78)).

So, what is a *fake closure*: A *fake closure* is a closure created from `Closure::fromCallable`.

This means, you have two options to fix your problem:

1. `Bar` must be compatible with the type of `Foo` - so just make `Bar`
   extend from `Foo`, if possible.
2. Use unbound functions, like annonymous, static or functions outside of classes.

Comment: To clarify on the "currently" part: This will never be supported. We have specifically prohibited this in PHP 7.1. Previously, it was possible to perform this kind of rebinding (of course, using ReflectionMethod::getClosure() rather than Closure::fromCallable(), which was only added in PHP 7.1), but this is no longer allowed.

Comment: @NikiC , are there any substantial reasons (like implementation problems or some ambiguities) for prohibiting this? I personally had a hard time facing the problem that could only be solved with a `$this` rebinding.

Comment: @rela589n People have a (very reasonable) expectation that `$this instanceof self` and we want to uphold that guarantee.

Comment: @NikiC , this can not be uphold completely. As anyone can bind any not fake closure to any class, what prevents someone from binding closure with same code as method of one class and binding it to another? Well, there's even no need to copy code of method as there's already package for it called `laravel/serializable-closure` which will read source code of method, create serialized closure from it so later on we can unserialize it.

Comment: @NikiC , I agree that `$this instanceof self` is reasonable and everyone should design their classes with this in mind. However when one create closure - it is not a method any longer. If we call it, we call it as closure, not as method. We ourself are responsible for how this logic will behave if `$this` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by PHP. However in PHP 7.0 it was kinda possible. Consider this example:

```php
class Foo {
    private $baz = 1;
    
    public function baz() {
        var_dump('Foo');
        var_dump($this->baz);
    }
}


class Bar {
    public $baz = 2;
    
    public function baz() {
        var_dump('Bar');
        var_dump($this->baz);
    }
}


$fooClass = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$method = $fooClass->getMethod('baz');

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

$closure = $method->getClosure($foo);

$closure2 = $closure->bindTo($bar);

$closure2();
```

The output of foregoing code is:

```
string(3) "Foo"
int(2)
```

And this means method `Foo::baz` was called on object `$bar` and has accessed its `$baz` property rather than `Foo::$baz`.

Also, please note that `Bar::$baz` is public property. If it was private, php would throw Fatal error cannot access private property. This could've be fixed up by changing the scope of closure `$closure->bindTo($bar, $bar);`, however doing this was already prohibited in php7.0 and would lead to a following warning: `Cannot rebind scope of closure created by ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosure()`.

**There's workaround however**, which will work for latest versions of php. Laravel created a splendid package called `laravel/serializable-closure`. What it does is simple - it reads source code of closure in order to serialize it and be able to unserialize it later with all necessary context.

So basically the functionality of unserialized closure remains the same, however it is different from PHP's perspective. PHP doesn't know it was created from class method and therefore allows to bind any `$this`.

Final variant will look like this:

```php
$callback = [$foo, 'baz'];

$closure = unserialize(
    serialize(new SerializableClosure(Closure::fromCallable($callback)))
)->getClosure();

$closure->call($bar);
```

Please, note that serialization and unserialization are expensive operations, so do not use provided solution unless there's no other solution.