# How do I make a method of a class a closure in php?

Tags: php, closures, call

```
<?php

class Container
{
    public $say = 'hi';
}

class Loader
{
    public function callSay()
    {
        echo $this->say;
    }
}

$container = new Container;
$run1 = function () {
    echo $this->say;
};
$run1->call($container); //hi

$loader = new Loader;
$run2 = function () use ($loader) {
    $loader->callSay();
};
$run2->call($container); //Undefined property: Loader::$say
```

I've tried to make $loader->callSay() into a closure and apply it to $container but it doesn't work.

How can I make a method inside a class a closure and then bind it to another class?

Comment: well there isn't a say member in loader to begin with, unless you want to extend container there, then it'll work

Comment: or another way is to instatiate container inside loader if you happen to not want loader to be extended

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - convert a method to a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701482/php-convert-a-method-to-a-closure)

Comment: I think this is a different matter. The posts presented are applied within the same class. This is an application between different classes.
$closure = Closure::fromCallable($run2);
$run2->call($container); Still doesn't work....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP binding method to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165930/php-binding-method-to-another-class)

Comment: OK. Very disappointing, but now I know that's impossible. I need to find another way. Anyway thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callSay method of the Loader class wants to access the say property. The property say does not exist.
The easiest way is to create this property and fill it with your value.

```
$run2 = function() use ($loader) {
  $loader->say = $this->say;  
  $loader->callSay();
};
```